# Quest 'Strange beast': Talk to Thorleif fails when you reach the ambush site

Tags: the-witcher-3

Geralt spoke with Thorleif at Larvik and got his 'Strange beast' quest. The 'Talk to Thorleif' part is green and solved in the quest log until you reach the ambush site. As soon as you use your witcher sense and investigate items, the part 'Talk to Thorleif' changes to failed and red.

Is this a bug or what should I do exactly between talking to Thorleif and going to the ambush site outside Larvik?

Comment: Sometimes when you click on the red sub-quest line, there is an explanation below about what you did that failed that part of the quest. Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Unfortunately, none of my red entries gives any additional ifnormation. Do you play on PC?

Comment: Yes I play on PC.

Comment: can it be that you need to talk with Thorleif a bit more ? Cause i think he needs to follow you and "investigate" everything with you

Answer (score -1):

Try talking to the warriors in the village after talking to Thorleif before investigating.